# Why list of Composable does not work in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

i'm trying to learn compose  but i don't understand why list inferred type is `List<Unit>` instead of `List<()->Unit>` . moreover `startingPoint()` in `setContent` does not work.

```
    @Composable
    fun AudioScreen() {
        Text(text = "dhgghf")}
    @Composable
    fun SearchScreen() {Text(text = "dhgghf")}
    

    @Composable
    fun startingPoint() {
        val menurou  = listOf(AudioScreen(),SearchScreen())
        menurou[0]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because the function AudioScreen and SearchScreen are returning Unit and not () -> Unit. But this has nothing to do with composable.. Lets look at the following example

```
fun firstFunction(): () -> Unit = { Unit }

val listForFirstFunction: List<() -> Unit> = listOf(firstFuntion())

fun secondFunction(): Unit = Unit

val listForSecondFunction: List<Unit> = listOf(secondFunction)
```

Because firstFunction is returning a `() -> Unit` the type of listForFirstFunction gets `() -> Unit`. Same goes with secondFunction which returns Unit and therefore the type of listForSecondFunction is Unit.

But if you want to save secondFunction as () -> Unit, you can do this by writing:

```
val thirdListForFunction = listOf( {secondFunction()} )
```

which then gives you the ability to write `thirdListForFunction[0].invoke()`

---

> moreover startingPoint() in setContent does not work.

I think you are asking why `menurou[0]` is not working right? Thats because `menurou[0]` simply just returns Unit, but not the desired function AudioScreen()